# Facebook Sharing: Reauthentication Issue

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am facing a problem with Facebook's share dialog using the javascript sdk.

My share dialog works as below (perfectly) in 2 cases:

1. If I have my website open and am not logged into Facebook, and then click on share, it asks me to log in and then opens the share dialog.
2. If I have my website open and am already logged into Facebook, and then click on share, it directly opens the share dialog.

However,

3. If I open my website while I am logged into Facebook, and then log out from Facebook without reloading my website, and then click on share button, it sticks and continues loading.

If I am already logged out from facebook and then open my website and click on share button then it works for all the 3 cases I mentioned above.

### Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //Initialize facebook
    FB.init({
        appId : 'MY_APP_ID',
        xfbml : true,
        version : 'v2.0'
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#post_image_href").click(function(e) {
        /* Important Variables */
        var url='';
        var imgToShare = '';
        var currentUrl = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
        var title=document.title;
        e.preventDefault();
        imgToShare =$('#wrap22 img:first').attr('src');
        imgToShare = encodeURIComponent(imgToShare);

        FB.ui( {
            method: "share",
            href: currentUrl+"?imgToShare="+imgToShare
        },function(response){
            if (response && !response.error_code) {
                $('#facebook_sharing').modal("show");
                $('#share_result').html("Your image has been shared successfully.");
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#facebook_sharing').modal("hide");
                }, 2000);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you reformat that javascript to make it a bit more readable?